# run os x screencapture from emacs call-process

Tags: macos, emacs, screenshot

I would like to generate a screenshot on OS X from within emacs with interactive selection of the region.

On the command line this works as expected

```
screencapture -i ~/test.png
```

The file is not created, though, when I call this using (call-process ...)

```
(call-process "screencapture" nil nil nil "-i" "~/test.png")
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running it with the third argument set to `t`, to insert the output from the command in the current buffer.  It says:

```
screencapture: cannot write file to intended destination, ~/test.png
```

That is because the `~` abbreviation for the home directory is expanded by the shell, but `call-process` bypasses the shell and passes the arguments directly to the command.  Try specifying the path explicitly instead, for example like this:

```
(call-process "screencapture" nil nil nil "-i" "/Users/me/test.png")
```